# Convert tuple of tuples into dict ---- do not ignore the value when the key has already exist

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

input:

```
a = (("s", 3), ("c", 6), ("s", 8))
dict(a)
```

output:

```
{"s": 3, "c": 6}
```

How can I get the following result?

```
{"s": (3, 8), "c": 6}
```

Comment: Why is element `c` not a tuple?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = (("s", 3), ("c", 6), ("s", 8))
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for c, num in a:
        d[c].append(num)


>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'s': [3, 8], 'c': [6]})
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `defauldict` for such simple case. People usually don't understand it and may use as a normal `dict` (hint: it'll never raise the `KeyError`'s they expect).

Comment: @JBernardo That sounds like personal preference. Sure you can achieve the same result with `.setdefault` but this looks a lot nicer imo, anyway that's just a personal view. As for the `KeyError` you would "expect" accessing with `d[n]`, you won't be importing and using `defaultdict` without a reason for it, the name kinda gives it away, it's pretty explicit about having a *default* value.

Answer (score 2):

use `setdefault()` and `c` should be a list:

```
>>> a = (("s",3), ("c",6), ("s",8))
>>> dic={}
>>> for x in a:
    dic.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])


>>> dic
{'s': [3, 8], 'c': [6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `groupby` (although I'd go `defaultdict`) which means you can be left with tuples fairly easily if you need them:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig

a = (("s", 3), ("c", 6), ("s", 8))    
newdict = { k:tuple(map(ig(1), v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(a), ig(0)) }
```